# Select From 2 Selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help I have 3 tables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3MX.jpg

My code:

```
select nazev_produkt,
SUM(mnozstvi_objednavka_dod)'bylo na sklade'
from Produkty p join Objednavky_dodavatele od on 
p.id_produkt=od.id_produkt
where stavzbozi_objednavka_dod=('na skladě')
group by nazev_produkt



select nazev_produkt,SUM(mnozstvi_objednavka_zak)koupili  
from Objednavky_zakaznici oz join Produkty p 
on oz.id_produkt=p.id_produkt
where stav_objednavka_zak=('dodané')
group by nazev_produkt
```

I want to create select code from both of this selected which will consist of nazev_produkt, 'bylo na sklade - koupili' and group by nazev_produkt

basically 
bylo na sklade = was in stock

koupili = purchased.

I need to deduct the purchased - was in stock and show nazev_produkt (Product Name), na sklade (In Stock)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a tip: coding in English makes it easier to get help, find web resources and is also an important professional skill. I'm German and I code in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't read your language, so making a few guesses here...  :-)  The table joining, I think, answers your question in any case.

```
select
   p.product_name,
   --isnull(i.quantity,0) as was_in_stock,
   --isnull(s.quantity,0) as sold,
   isnull(i.quantity,0) - isnull(s.quantity,0) as [currently_in_stock]
from
   products p

   LEFT JOIN (select product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity from inventory group by product_id) i
   ON p.product_id = i.product_id

   LEFT JOIN (select product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity from sales group by product_id) s
   ON p.product_id = s.product_id
group by
   product_name
```

Comment: I have edited the code a bit but it doesn't work  http://pastebin.com/YyVVaPLf I'm getting the following error: `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column 'Objednavky_dodavatele.id_produkt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @user2778760 --  Sorry about that.  I fixed it above (added 'group by' clause to inventory and sales queries)

Answer (score 0):

Add a third column with the typization of your source.

Try this:

```
select nazev_produkt,
isnull(
    (select SUM(mnozstvi_objednavka_dod)
    from Objednavky_dodavatele od 
    where p.id_produkt=od.id_produkt),
0) -
isnull(
    (select SUM(mnozstvi_objednavka_zak)
    from Objednavky_zakaznici oz
    where oz.id_produkt=p.id_produkt),
0)
from Produkty p
where stavzbozi_objednavka_dod=('na sklade')
or stav_objednavka_zak=('dodané')
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for trying to help me I need only 2 column 1 Is  `nazev_produkt` and second column lets call it `Stock` equals `bylo na sklade` amount minus (-) `koupili` amount = Stock amount

Comment: @user2778760: I've changed my query. I'm not sure on these filters where stavzbozi_objednavka_dod=('na sklade')
or stav_objednavka_zak=('dodané'). Peraphs can be removed but I've trouble with translations :)